# App to find empty Windows folders

Tags: windows, gratis, file-management, directories

I don't want to delete them, just find them.

Displaying them graphically, as a tree, or a list is enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the simplest answer [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-files/how-do-i-find-all-the-empty-folders-and-delete/3a7b5a35-1b5e-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5?auth=1) - built in to Windows.

> If you do want to delete all the empty folders only, go to Computer
>   and at the top right click on search. Click on kind and Select folder,
>   now click again on search and click on size, select 0 and click on
>   search.

That worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

1. Install [Python](https://www.python.org/) selecting the option to add it to your path
2. Open a command prompt
3. cd to your starting point
4. type: `python`
5. type in the following, (indenting is important):

```
import os
for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk('.'):
    if len(dirs)+len(files) == 0:
        print (root)
```

You will get the list starting from where you are.

- The above is free, gratis & open source
- It will work on just about any platform
- Note that if you wish to start from a specific directory you an by changing `os.walk('.')` to `os.walk(r'C:\Some\Dir')` *the `r` is important if you would like to use `\` rather than `/`*

Comment: Lols - I never thought of coding it myself :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Ffind](http://bvdsw.com/ffind/) Ext.

1. Type: d
2. Empty

[image: Find empty directories - Ffind Ext]

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool with the self-explanatory name [Remove Empty Directories](http://www.jonasjohn.de/red.htm).

[image: main screen]

Comment: Please read questions carefully. The original question clearly states that the OP doesn't want to delete those folders.